# Talend: tMap only generates Main outputs, not Lookup outputs

Tags: input, mapping, output, talend

When working with Talend, I find that when trying to create outputs for my tMap components, the only type I can create is `*New output* (Main)`. Yet, I need to create Lookup outputs.
(to pipe to other tMaps that already have a Main input).

Does somebody know the cause of this issue and/or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction Main/Lookup has only sense with incoming connections. From the outgoing connection scope, there's no difference between lookup or main: it's just a vectorized stream of data.

Pratically speaking, this means you can simply connect the main connection of your wanna-be-lookup tMap to the real-main tMap: since you cannot have more than  one main connection, the additional one(s) will be automatically marked as lookup connection(s).

You can change the flow type for your incoming connections (from main to lookup and vice-versa) at any time doing a right-click on your connection, then "Change connection order"

It's quite easy to mess-up your mind while doing this. Just remember that your main connection is the one which starts with the component that has a green background.

[image]

Comment: All right, so theoretically I always create an output stream with *New output* (Main) and then it adjusts to the connected element to become either a Main or an Lookup stream. Then still, my case is a weird one, because when I try to create a stream from Map1 (which has no outputs yet) to Map2 (which already has a main input) it is simply impossible (The plug with the crossed sign appears). It does *not* create a Lookup stream automatically... Any clues?

Comment: That's weird. I don't exclude some metadata mess in your job, which is something not so uncommon in Talend workspace. That's exacly what I meant when I said how easy is to mess up connection scope. Is the green component still where it's supposed to be? If so, the next step to tryis creating the outgoing wanna-be-lookup from inside the tMap wizard (click on the "+" button on top of the right side of the UI) rather than using the contextual menu. If still messed-up, try creating a brand-new job from scratch: Talend is definitively still not bug-free, from this point of view.

Comment: Not sure about the green background. I only have one component with green background (the MSSQLInput1) but there's more inputs on the screen, one of which is MSSQLInput2, which is pointing to Map1. The MSSQLInput2 *does* import data and the rows *do* flow to Map1. Creating the output stream from Map1 either through the wizard or by dragging gives the same behaviour: I *can* create main outputs (to a fresh Map3) but *not* lookup outputs (to the aforementioned Map2 or any other already inputted Map or object).

Comment: Still unable to reproduce. Have a look at the screenshot I added. It shows the starting (main) component (the green one) and how all subsequents connections become lookups. Did you try a brand-new job? As I said, metadata corruption is not so uncommon on Talend

Comment: Going from your screenshot, I've narrowed down the issue to this: when you add another tMap4, and connect a Main from tMap3 to tMap4, then it is impossible to add a lookup from tMap4. Can you reproduce that? If so, I think it has something to do with tMap3 already 'giving out' a lookup, and then somehow itself and its Main connections down the chain (tMap4 in this case) are unable to create Lookup outputs...

Comment: Still not able to reproduce, but maybe I got it now; it happened to me sometimes, actually. Basically, things went weird if you try to connect lookups to tMaps in reverse order. But what I would like to point you out is that by the very inner design of Talend (well, of ETL) you cannot make "closed paths" inside your dataflows. This mean that a tMAp cannot gives up two lookups at same time, as this would end to a merge into the main flow at some time, closing the path. If this is the case, you need to redesign the job using temp tables or tHash* components to store the data in memory meanwhile.

Comment: I'll definitely check out temp tables and/or hash components. Probably that is what I'm looking for..! Thank you so much for your support and ongoing investigation! :-) Is there, as a last pointer, a good resoure about these closed loops in ETL? I don't completely understand that concept and how two lookups would create a closed loop... But I won't bother you with that, and instead do my homework! :-)

Comment: just check by yourself, it's much easier than trying to explain :) design a job trying to source two lookups from the same tMap to two target tMaps in the same main flow :)

Comment: Correct. I can check that that won't work, but the question remains *why* it doesn't work :-) Any pointers?

Comment: You can work it out just reversing the code generated by Talend itself. You may see that subjobs (defined as blue-squared sequence of elements) share the same java scope (in other words: all components share the same set of attributes and methods). If you "close the loop" you'll give an ambigous definition of vectors to Talend code generator, hence Talend won't be able to distinguish between connections. So, it's forbidden by design. For the same reasons, and altough it's not strictly related to ETL foundations themselves, you won't find a ETL tool that allows to close loops so easily.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..! It's all clear now! :-)